# Vagrant: mysql don't start if shared /var/lib/mysql

Tags: mysql, vagrant

I provision the machine with a shell script, install mysql-community-server and start (work's), if add this line to Vagrantfile, mysql server don't start

```
config.vm.synced_folder "mysql", "/var/lib/mysql"
```

Instead, the same command for apache works

```
config.vm.synced_folder "http", "/var/www/html"
```

Any idea?

Comment: Do you get any error messages, etc.?

Comment: No, during startup it blocked to "service mysqld start", from /var/log/mysqld.log > cannot create ./ibdata1, problem of permission

Comment: Have you tried passing the user and group to the `config.vm.synced_folder` ? https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/basic_usage.html

Comment: If i use `config.vm.synced_folder "mysql", "/var/lib/mysql", owner: "mysql", group: "mysql"`i have this error `Failed to mount folders in Linux guest. This is usually beacuse
the "vboxsf" file system is not available. Please verify that
the guest additions are properly installed in the guest and
can work properly.` The guest addition is installed...the sharing of http works!

Comment: can you try disable the start of sql from service and see if the folder can be mounted. I can imagine there is conflict when folder is shared if service is writing into it some info about the startup.

Answer (score 0):

If your host is an OSX, it is a permission problem.
Go to the host, right click on the folder and change the permission for everyone to read-write.